# HTTP Status Code for incompatible columns in a reporting API

Tags: api, http, rest

The reporting API has a number of columns, but not all columns can be combined into a single report. When a request specifies incompatible columns, what is the most canonical HTTP Status code to return?

So far, I've come up with either a [422](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) or a [409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.10).

Either one would require a description of the conflicting columns so that the requestor can correct and resubmit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 409 Conflict implies a conflict with the current state of the resource. There is no such conflict, so that's not right.

422 Unprocessable Entity looks more correct. I would also argue that 400 Bad Request would not be unreasonable.

Comment: I think 422 is the correct status code here. 400 is meant to indicate that the request was malformed. In this scenario, the request is well-formed, so 422 is better than 400.

Comment: The conflict I was thinking of is that we do not have a way to join the two columns, but may in the future. But, I think you are right, 422 is better/cleaner.